# Run a PML macro automatically when i login to AVEVA PDMS / E3D

Tags: c#, macros

Hi i am using AVEVA PDMS / E3D for designing piping route and AVEVA has a programming language called PML. i wonder is there any way to run a PML macro automatically when i login into the PDMS / E3D?
Thank you

Comment: According to [Aveva](https://www.aveva.com/en/contact/): _We’re here to provide information, support and training wherever and whenever you need it, 24/7_. Have you used the customer support tools offered by the company who created the product?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches to do this:

- [PML Addins](https://help.aveva.com/AVEVA_Everything3D/3.1/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=PMLPUG/PMLCG24.27.01.html) which are defined by files in the **PMLUI** directory, and which allow executing PML code at a certain time (for example when changing a module)
- [.NET Addins](https://help.aveva.com/AVEVA_Everything3D/3.1/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=NCUG/NCUG2.03.01.html) which allow you to execute a .NET code when the application starts

If you use the second option and you want to call a PML code from your .NET code, you just have to use the **Aveva.Core.Utilities.CommandLine.Command** class.

Here is an example of an Addin in C# which executes the function **!!initPipeRouting()** at startup:

```
public class PipeRouterAddin : IAddinInjected
{
    public string Name => nameof(PipeRouterAddin);

    public string Description => "Pipe Router Addin";

    public void Start(IDependencyResolver resolver)
    {
        Aveva.Core.Utilities.CommandLine.Command.CreateCommand("!!initPipeRouting()").RunInPdms();
    }

    public void Start(ServiceManager serviceManager)
    {
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
    }
}
```